# Generate evenly spaced points on 2D graph

Tags: geometry, prime-factorization, image-processing

I want to draw dots on an image that is W by W pixels. The image is stored as a 1-D array of pixels. The pixel (x,y) is at array index x + y * W.  I am thinking that I can use a fixed step size, N, and draw a dot at every Nth pixel. What value of N will produce equilateral triangles?

Here is the result using W = 100 and N = 673
[image: W = 100 and N = 673]

As you can see the triangles formed are nearly equilateral. Given W, how can I find "good" values for N, which will form near equilateral triangles?

Comment: Are there any constraints (e.g. upper or lower limit) regarding the number of produced triangles?

Comment: No constraints. N and W must be positive integers. If you plot the minimum distance between any two points as a function of N (with W fixed), you can see the function has many maxima. The "nearly equilateral triangles" correspond to the maxima. I'd like to predict what the maxima will be for a given W.

Comment: On second thought, allowing N and W to be Real won't change the answer, and it might be easier to solve. Given W and index I = k*N, the coordinates of the point is (x,y) where x is the remainder and y is the quotient, of I/W. (So I guess y is an integer, but x needn't be).

Answer (score -1):

I doubt if there is a simple answer to this question. Below is a plot of the "goodness" of the 10 triangles that can be formed using the first five points. Goodness is min side length over max side length. W = 100, and the first point is at (50,0). The horizontal axis is N, from 600 to 1200.

[image]

You can see there are 10 peaks above 0.9 goodness. These correspond to N = 628, 674, 726, 759, 826, 860, 926, 1026, 1137, 1165. The very last "good" spot is at N = 2850 where the points 0,1,2 form a nearly equilateral triangle. I have a theory that for any W, there will be an nearly equilateral formed when N = 0.2885 * W^2 (approximately).

Comment: I think the spacing of the indices of the three points that form each triangle is key to solving the problem. Given W, N, and two positive integers s, t, the three points with indices a, b = a + s*N, c = b + t*N will form a triangle. Maximize the goodness of the triangle over N. I think there is just one maximum for each s,t pair. I may look into it more.